# Detailed implementation of IEEE754 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, ieee-754

In MATLAB,

```
>> format hex; 3/10, 3*0.1
ans =
   3fd3333333333333
ans =
   3fd3333333333334

>> 3/10 - 3*0.1
ans = 
   bc90000000000000
```

Is this result predictable? i.e. I can follow some rules of floating point arithmetic, and get `3/10 = 3d3333333333333, 3*0.1 = 3d3333333333334` again by hand.

Comment: Probably yes. Because you perform two different operations. The first one is a division whereas the second one is a multiplication (by the inverse).

Comment: Those [class notes [pdf]](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi07/cse140/IEEE754.pdf) are quite good to explain how you can manually calculate the division and multiplication in IEEE754. Just use binary or hexadecimal representation to compare it with your MATLAB results above. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The rules are:

1. In MATLAB, unless specified otherwise (via constructors), all literals have double precision in the sense of IEE754 standard: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html
2. All arithmetic operations are executed according to the usual precedence rules: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html
3. When mixing numeric types with `double` in an arithmetic operation, MATLAB converts the `double` to the other numeric type before executing the operation—as opposed to C, for example, which does the other way around.

By using these rules you can pretty much predict the results of any arithmetic expression (always little endian memory layout, bit patterns are two's complement for signed integers and IEEE754 for floats). The alternative is to let MATLAB apply the rules for you; the results will be consistent and repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when creating the binary representation for 0.1 a roundup has occurred, introducing a small error:

```
>> 0.1
ans =
   3fb999999999999a
```

There should be infinitely many of those 9s in the end but we cut it and round up the last digit. The error is small but becomes significant when you multiply by 3

```
>> 3*0.1
ans =
   3fd3333333333334
```

When correctly calculated by division this last digit shouldn't be 4:

```
>> 3/10
ans =
   3fd3333333333333
```

It is interesting to see that this error is not big enough to cause a problem when we multiply by some other number smaller than 3 (the threshold is not exactly 3 though):

```
>> 2.9/10
ans =
   3fd28f5c28f5c28f
>> 2.9*0.1
ans =
   3fd28f5c28f5c28f
```

Comment: "the threshold is not exactly 3 though" <- there is no "threshold": you'll find numbers `x` for which `x / 10.0` and `x * 0.1` differ across the entire floating-point range, and you'll also find numbers for which they agree across the entire range.